# C++ error: no match for call to ‘(RgbImage) (int&, int&)’

Tags: c++, for-loop

The pseudo code I'm trying to follow for this implementation:

```
for (int u = 0; u < uMax; u++)
{   for (int v = 0; v < vMax; v++)
    {   float x = f_x(u, v);
        float y = f_y(u, v);

        dstImage(x, y) = srcImage(u, v);
    }
}
```

The scaling function I'm trying to implement the above code with.   I iterate over each pixel just as I did to change the r,g,b, but I'm having issues changing the value of the x.  I've implemented code for this to change the r,g,b of the image but I would now like to be able to scale the x of the image by a factor of 2.  This is the attempt to scale x the in the same way as changing r,g,b.

```
void scale()
{
    RgbImage theTexMap( filename ); // loaded from some file name
    //RgbImage destination;
    double r, g, b; // variables to store the different colours
    float u, v;
    for (int x = 0; x < theTexMap.GetNumRows(); x++)
    {   for (int y = 0; y < theTexMap.GetNumCols(); y++)
        {   theTexMap.GetRgbPixel(x, y, &r, &g, &b);  //this successfully allows me to change the r,g,b values
            u = x * 2;
            v = y;
            //cout << x <<endl;
            //cout << y << " " << endl;
            //cout << " " <<endl;
            destination.SetRgbPixelf(u, v, r, g, b); //allows me to set r,g,b values, fails with the x,y.
        }
    }

    updateTexture(&destination, modifiedID);

}
```

According to the Pseudo  code I'm trying to follow, it should be more like this. (changed inside of for loops and used u,v iteration)

```
void scale()
{
    RgbImage theTexMap( filename ); // loaded from some file name
    //RgbImage destination;
    double r, g, b; // variables to store the different colours
    float x, y;
    for (int u = 0; u < theTexMap.GetNumRows(); u++)
    {   for (int v = 0; v < theTexMap.GetNumCols(); v++)
        {   x = u * 2;
            y = v;
            //cout << x <<endl;
            //cout << y << " " << endl;
            //cout << " " <<endl;
            theTexMap(x,y) = theTexMap(u,v)
        }
    }

    updateTexture(&theTexMap, modifiedID);

}
```

Now because I don't really understand the pseudo code for that last line, I get this error message when I call it in my implementation. The error message I receive.

`error: no match for call to ‘(RgbImage) (float&, float&)’
        theTexMap(x,y) = theTexMap(u,v);`

Well now your saying, I don't know what RgbImage (the type of theTexMap) is you dummy.  So here's it's class.  Should I be using it in this case like the above?  Or how should I follow that pseudo code to get my desired factor of 2 scaling?

```
#include "RgbImage.h"

#ifndef RGBIMAGE_DONT_USE_OPENGL
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include "GL/gl.h"
#endif

RgbImage::RgbImage( int numRows, int numCols )
{
    NumRows = numRows;
    NumCols = numCols;
    ImagePtr = new unsigned char[NumRows*GetNumBytesPerRow()];
    if ( !ImagePtr ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for %ld x %ld bitmap.\n", 
                NumRows, NumCols);
        Reset();
        ErrorCode = MemoryError;
    }
    // Zero out the image
    unsigned char* c = ImagePtr;
    int rowLen = GetNumBytesPerRow();
    for ( int i=0; i<NumRows; i++ ) {
        for ( int j=0; j<rowLen; j++ ) {
            *(c++) = 0;
        }
    }
}


bool RgbImage::LoadBmpFile( const char* filename ) 
{  
    Reset();
    FILE* infile = fopen( filename, "rb" );     // Open for reading binary data
    if ( !infile ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", filename);
        ErrorCode = OpenError;
        return false;
    }

    bool fileFormatOK = false;
    int bChar = fgetc( infile );
    int mChar = fgetc( infile );
    if ( bChar=='B' && mChar=='M' ) {           // If starts with "BM" for "BitMap"
        skipChars( infile, 4+2+2+4+4 );         // Skip 4 fields we don't care about
        NumCols = readLong( infile );
        NumRows = readLong( infile );
        skipChars( infile, 2 );                 // Skip one field
        int bitsPerPixel = readShort( infile );
        skipChars( infile, 4+4+4+4+4+4 );       // Skip 6 more fields

        if ( NumCols>0 && NumCols<=100000 && NumRows>0 && NumRows<=100000  
            && bitsPerPixel==24 && !feof(infile) ) {
            fileFormatOK = true;
        }
    }
    if ( !fileFormatOK ) {
        Reset();
        ErrorCode = FileFormatError;
        fprintf(stderr, "Not a valid 24-bit bitmap file: %s.\n", filename);
        fclose ( infile );
        return false;
    }

    // Allocate memory
    ImagePtr = new unsigned char[NumRows*GetNumBytesPerRow()];
    if ( !ImagePtr ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for %ld x %ld bitmap: %s.\n", 
                NumRows, NumCols, filename);
        Reset();
        ErrorCode = MemoryError;
        fclose ( infile );
        return false;
    }

    unsigned char* cPtr = ImagePtr;
    for ( int i=0; i<NumRows; i++ ) {
        int j;
        for ( j=0; j<NumCols; j++ ) {
            *(cPtr+2) = fgetc( infile );    // Blue color value
            *(cPtr+1) = fgetc( infile );    // Green color value
            *cPtr = fgetc( infile );        // Red color value
            cPtr += 3;
        }
        int k=3*NumCols;                    // Num bytes already read
        for ( ; k<GetNumBytesPerRow(); k++ ) {
            fgetc( infile );                // Read and ignore padding;
            *(cPtr++) = 0;
        }
    }
    if ( feof( infile ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Premature end of file: %s.\n", filename );
        Reset();
        ErrorCode = ReadError;
        fclose ( infile );
        return false;
    }
    fclose( infile );   // Close the file
    return true;
}

short RgbImage::readShort( FILE* infile )
{
    // read a 16 bit integer
    unsigned char lowByte, hiByte;
    lowByte = fgetc(infile);            // Read the low order byte (little endian form)
    hiByte = fgetc(infile);         // Read the high order byte

    // Pack together
    short ret = hiByte;
    ret <<= 8;
    ret |= lowByte;
    return ret;
}

long RgbImage::readLong( FILE* infile )
{  
    // Read in 32 bit integer
    unsigned char byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3;
    byte0 = fgetc(infile);          // Read bytes, low order to high order
    byte1 = fgetc(infile);
    byte2 = fgetc(infile);
    byte3 = fgetc(infile);

    // Pack together
    long ret = byte3;
    ret <<= 8;
    ret |= byte2;
    ret <<= 8;
    ret |= byte1;
    ret <<= 8;
    ret |= byte0;
    return ret;
}

void RgbImage::skipChars( FILE* infile, int numChars )
{
    for ( int i=0; i<numChars; i++ ) {
        fgetc( infile );
    }
}

bool RgbImage::WriteBmpFile( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* outfile = fopen( filename, "wb" );        // Open for reading binary data
    if ( !outfile ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", filename);
        ErrorCode = OpenError;
        return false;
    }

    fputc('B',outfile);
    fputc('M',outfile);
    int rowLen = GetNumBytesPerRow();
    writeLong( 40+14+NumRows*rowLen, outfile ); // Length of file
    writeShort( 0, outfile );                   // Reserved for future use
    writeShort( 0, outfile );
    writeLong( 40+14, outfile );                // Offset to pixel data
    writeLong( 40, outfile );                   // header length
    writeLong( NumCols, outfile );              // width in pixels
    writeLong( NumRows, outfile );              // height in pixels (pos for bottom up)
    writeShort( 1, outfile );       // number of planes
    writeShort( 24, outfile );      // bits per pixel
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // no compression
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // not used if no compression
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // Pixels per meter
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // Pixels per meter
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // unused for 24 bits/pixel
    writeLong( 0, outfile );        // unused for 24 bits/pixel

    // Now write out the pixel data:
    unsigned char* cPtr = ImagePtr;
    for ( int i=0; i<NumRows; i++ ) {
        // Write out i-th row's data
        int j;
        for ( j=0; j<NumCols; j++ ) {
            fputc( *(cPtr+2), outfile);     // Blue color value
            fputc( *(cPtr+1), outfile);     // Blue color value
            fputc( *(cPtr+0), outfile);     // Blue color value
            cPtr+=3;
        }
        // Pad row to word boundary
        int k=3*NumCols;                    // Num bytes already read
        for ( ; k<GetNumBytesPerRow(); k++ ) {
            fputc( 0, outfile );                // Read and ignore padding;
            cPtr++;
        }
    }

    fclose( outfile );  // Close the file
    return true;
}

void RgbImage::writeLong( long data, FILE* outfile )
{  
    // Read in 32 bit integer
    unsigned char byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3;
    byte0 = (unsigned char)(data&0x000000ff);       // Write bytes, low order to high order
    byte1 = (unsigned char)((data>>8)&0x000000ff);
    byte2 = (unsigned char)((data>>16)&0x000000ff);
    byte3 = (unsigned char)((data>>24)&0x000000ff);

    fputc( byte0, outfile );
    fputc( byte1, outfile );
    fputc( byte2, outfile );
    fputc( byte3, outfile );
}

void RgbImage::writeShort( short data, FILE* outfile )
{  
    // Read in 32 bit integer
    unsigned char byte0, byte1;
    byte0 = data&0x000000ff;        // Write bytes, low order to high order
    byte1 = (data>>8)&0x000000ff;

    fputc( byte0, outfile );
    fputc( byte1, outfile );
}


/*********************************************************************
 * SetRgbPixel routines allow changing the contents of the RgbImage. *
 *********************************************************************/

void RgbImage::SetRgbPixelf( long row, long col, double red, double green, double blue )
{
    SetRgbPixelc( row, col, doubleToUnsignedChar(red), 
                            doubleToUnsignedChar(green),
                            doubleToUnsignedChar(blue) );
}

void RgbImage::SetRgbPixelc( long row, long col,
                   unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue )
{
    assert ( row<NumRows && col<NumCols );
    unsigned char* thePixel = GetRgbPixel( row, col );
    *(thePixel++) = red;
    *(thePixel++) = green;
    *(thePixel) = blue;
}


unsigned char RgbImage::doubleToUnsignedChar( double x )
{
    if ( x>=1.0 ) {
        return (unsigned char)255;
    }
    else if ( x<=0.0 ) {
        return (unsigned char)0;
    }
    else {
        return (unsigned char)(x*255.0);        // Rounds down
    }
}
// Bitmap file format  (24 bit/pixel form)      BITMAPFILEHEADER
// Header (14 bytes)
//   2 bytes: "BM"
//   4 bytes: long int, file size
//   4 bytes: reserved (actually 2 bytes twice)
//   4 bytes: long int, offset to raster data
// Info header (40 bytes)                       BITMAPINFOHEADER
//   4 bytes: long int, size of info header (=40)
//   4 bytes: long int, bitmap width in pixels
//   4 bytes: long int, bitmap height in pixels
//   2 bytes: short int, number of planes (=1)
//   2 bytes: short int, bits per pixel
//   4 bytes: long int, type of compression (not applicable to 24 bits/pixel)
//   4 bytes: long int, image size (not used unless compression is used)
//   4 bytes: long int, x pixels per meter
//   4 bytes: long int, y pixels per meter
//   4 bytes: colors used (not applicable to 24 bit color)
//   4 bytes: colors important (not applicable to 24 bit color)
// "long int" really means "unsigned long int"
// Pixel data: 3 bytes per pixel: RGB values (in reverse order).
//  Rows padded to multiples of four.


#ifndef RGBIMAGE_DONT_USE_OPENGL

bool RgbImage::LoadFromOpenglBuffer()                   // Load the bitmap from the current OpenGL buffer
{
    int viewportData[4];
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewportData );
    int& vWidth = viewportData[2];
    int& vHeight = viewportData[3];

    if ( ImagePtr==0 ) { // If no memory allocated
        NumRows = vHeight;
        NumCols = vWidth;
        ImagePtr = new unsigned char[NumRows*GetNumBytesPerRow()];
        if ( !ImagePtr ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for %ld x %ld buffer.\n", 
                    NumRows, NumCols);
            Reset();
            ErrorCode = MemoryError;
            return false;
        }
    }
    assert ( vWidth>=NumCols && vHeight>=NumRows );
    int oldGlRowLen;
    if ( vWidth>=NumCols ) {
        glGetIntegerv( GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, &oldGlRowLen );
        glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, NumCols );
    }
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    // Get the frame buffer data.
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, NumCols, NumRows, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ImagePtr);

    // Restore the row length in glPixelStorei  (really ought to restore alignment too).
    if ( vWidth>=NumCols ) {
        glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, oldGlRowLen );
    }   
    return true;
}

#endif   // RGBIMAGE_DONT_USE_OPENGL
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
theTexMap(x,y) = theTexMap(u,v);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is trying to invoke `RgbImage::operator()(float, float)`. That is not a defined operator on your type, hence the error.

I'm guessing the function you want to call is:

```
theTexMap.GetRgbPixel(u, v, &r, &g, &b);
theTexMap.SetRgbPixelf(x, y, r, g, b);
```

Comment: Looks good but it triggers an assert in the RgbImage class.  numCols doesn't change and makes our x value>numCols.